# Deprecated .crossFade() en Glide 4 de Android

Tags: java, android, android-glide

He actualizado de `Glide 3.8.0` a `Glide 4.1.1` y me encuentro que parte de código ha dejado ser compatible

He seguido la instalación de [Started Glide 4](http://sjudd.github.io/glide/doc/generatedapi.html)

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.1.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.1.1'
```

Agregado el `MyAppGlideModule.java`

y usar `GlideApp` pero me encuentro que `.crossfade()` a desaparecido

Comment: Me estoy mirando http://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/migrating.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La nueva forma de agregar el efecto de desvanecimiento cruzado o en ingles crossfade es de la siguiente manera:

importar

```
import static com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.drawable.DrawableTransitionOptions.withCrossFade;
```

Luego lo aplicamos de la siguiente manera:

```
Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
  .load(url)
  .transition(withCrossFade())
  .into(imageView);
```

como se indica acá [Cross Fades Glide V4](http://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/migrating.html#cross-fades)